# Странный значок при выводе

Tags: php

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить одну проблему. Есть код

```
$name = 'Тут будет много букв, и вообще длинный текст.';

$len = mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8');

if($len > 27)
    echo substr($name, 0, 27);
```

И после выполнения этого кода, я получаю такую строчку

```
Тут будет мног�
```

Что это за значёк вконце, и как от него избавиться?

Comment: Знач**о**к. В конце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mb_substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php) вместо substr()

---

*Раз уж перевели мой комментарий в ответ, то наверно надо его как-то расширить...*

**strlen()** считает не "буковки" в строке, а байты. Символ кириллицы состоит из двух байт. Дальше матиматика: "*Тут будет мног*" - 26 байт (*пробелы по одному байту*), а последний 27-ой - это тот самый символ и, образно говоря, это половинка буквы "о". **mb_strlen()** - учитывает кодировку, указанную в параметре **encoding** или внутреннюю кодировку ([mb_internal_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)), если таковой параметр не задан. Поэтому странно, что вы длину строки высчитывали используя [многобайтную функцию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php), а дальше это не учли.